# How to add carousel (small size ) on top of another carousel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

//here is my carousel view which display some images on carousel code is below

```
Ext.define("App.view.GView", 
{
    extend:'Ext.Carousel',
    xtype:'GView',
    requires:[
        'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
        'Ext.Img',
        'Ext.Loader'
    ],

    config:{
        title:'XYZ',
        iconCls:'home',
        layout:{
            type:'vbox',
            pack:'center',
            align:'center'
        },
        directionLock:true,
        fullscreen:true,
        items:[
            {
                docked:'top',
                xtype:'titlebar',
                cls:'titleBar',
                title:'Gallery'
            }
        ],

        xtype:'carousel',
        id:'gallerycarousel'
    }
});
```

//Here is my controller code which binds data to

```
    var items = []; Temp array
    var xyz= [{ urlL}] My image array

    Ext.each(images, function (picture) {
    items.push({
            xtype: 'image',
             cls: 'centerImage',
             src: picture.url
           });
     });
    floorCarousel.setItems(items);
    floorCarousel.setActiveItem(0);
```

//My question is to how to add another carousel on the top this carousel that when i move first carousel item than second carousel item also should move and vice verse.. So first carousel is at bottom on top of that i need small size carousel Please help me out little tricky .,,

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  do you need to know how to create the carousel, or do you just need to know how to make the 2nd carousel move with the main carousel?

Comment: Hey hi the thing is that i am able to create carousel but i need to add another carousel on top of that. I am able to add that one. I am crating overlay in that  adding carousel and even i am able to move items from both carousel when item from one carousel is moved or else from both end. Thanks for your valuable reply .